# Getting illegal argument exception with elasticquent

Tags: laravel

I am trying to add my User model to indexes but doing

```
User::addAllToIndex()
```

results to this error

```
Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception with message '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]"},"status":400}'
```

I am following this tutorial
https://appdividend.com/2022/06/17/laravel-elasticsearch/

I have specified my index as `'default_index' => 'snake',`

Here is my User Model

```
use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, ElasticquentTrait;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'title',
    'body',
    'tags'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array<string, string>
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];



protected $indexSettings = [
    'analysis' => [
        'char_filter' => [
            'replace' => [
                'type' => 'mapping',
                'mappings' => [
                    '&=> and '
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'filter' => [
            'word_delimiter' => [
                'type' => 'word_delimiter',
                'split_on_numerics' => false,
                'split_on_case_change' => true,
                'generate_word_parts' => true,
                'generate_number_parts' => true,
                'catenate_all' => true,
                'preserve_original' => true,
                'catenate_numbers' => true,
            ]
        ],
        'analyzer' => [
            'default' => [
                'type' => 'custom',
                'char_filter' => [
                    'html_strip',
                    'replace',
                ],
                'tokenizer' => 'whitespace',
                'filter' => [
                    'lowercase',
                    'word_delimiter',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

and this is where I am adding index currently doing through my route file

```
Route::get("/",function(){

        User::addAllToIndex();
        return view('welcome');


    });
```

addAllToIndex will add the models records and everything should stored to the elasticsearch.

Comment: What does addAllToIndex do ?

Comment: It will add model records to Elasticsearch using elastiquent
Here are  details 
https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent

Comment: Post them here, not outside links

Comment: okay i am updating question